# How to setup cronjob with automated emails in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, sendmail

I've been working on creating a script to scan a series of mailboxes on a linux server, find ones that have more than 250 emails in the mailbox, and then send an email with the name of those mailboxes and how much mail each of them have.

Here is my mailboxcounter script to perform that:

```
ls /path to mailboxes/ -lR | grep rw | awk '{count[$3]++} END {for (word in count) if (count[word] > 250) print word, count[word]}'
```

Then I've attempted to create a cronjob in order to send out an email containing the mailboxes that match the criteria of the script on a regular schedule. I've set it to run every 5 min now just for testing purposes.

Here is that cronjob:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/sbin/sendmail name@email.com < <( bash /path/mailboxcounter.sh ) >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The first time I ran the cronjob, it worked flawlessly, but it never sent any other emails after the first one, let alone every 5 min. Additionally, I tried to add a few strings to clean up my original script like below:

```
ls /path to mailboxes/ -lR | grep rw | awk '{count[$3]++} END {for (word in count) if (count[word] > 25) print "Name: " word",", "emails in mailbox: " count[word]}'
```

But with these added strings, the cronjob won't send any emails anymore.

I've tried using the mail command and confirmed that mailx is installed on the server, but it never seems to work at all, so I've been sticking to using sendmail.

What am I missing here and how can I fix it so the cronjob will send the emails on a regular schedule while also adding the more descriptive strings to my original script without it failing to send emails? I feel like I'm close but have been failing with trial and error. Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: First rule of troubleshooting - don't discard output. Get rid of the redirect to `/dev/null` and see what cron has to say for itself.

Comment: Note that since you are already using `awk` there is no need for `grep` since `awk` can do pattern matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From man page

> Sendmail is not intended as a user interface routine; other programs provide user-friendly front ends; sendmail is used only to deliver pre-formatted messages

so you can reformat your messages or better use `mail`, `mailx`, `mutt`, etc.

#### update

Some examples using these commands can be found at https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/sending-emailssend-them-linux-terminal

Comment: Hmm, I've tried both the below mail commands but they won't send at all which is why I was working with sendmail:

1)  <./mailboxcounter.sh | mail -s "Mailbox Counter Test" name@email.com>

And just a simple test mail:

2)  <echo "Test Message" | mail -s "Mailbox Counter Test" name@email.com>

Is there something else that needs to be configured in order for the mail command to work?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this utilizing mailx rather than sendmail.

Example of the solution cronjob:

```
20 8 * * wed . ~/.bash_profile && cd /path | /path/mailboxcounter.sh | mail -s "Mailbox Counts" example@email.com
```